# How to convert object to Json in .net core 6 JsonConverter

Tags: json, .net-core, converters, json-serialization

Im trying to convert a object that looks like the object below into Json in .net core 6?

```
{{
  "Id": "178",
  "DisplayName": "Jon Doe",
  "Email": "JonDoe@gmail.com",
  "FullName": "Jon Doe",
  "UserName": "jdoe"
}}
```

Before upgrading to .net core 6 the object would automatically get converted to json and sent to the backend in the proper format. Without any converters it gets sent back as an empty [].

The route im currently trying is using JsonConverter in my Program.cs file but not sure if this route makes sense.

```
public class DataObjectConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<Object>
{

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
       //doesnt work 
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

The source value looks like below, but I convert it to the deserialized version above with this code. When I try to serialize it back is were the problem happens.

```
var deserializeSourceData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(sourceData)
```

Source looks like this

```
"{\"Id\":\"178\",\"DisplayName\":\"Jon Doe\",\"Email\":\"JonDoe@jpl.nasa.gov\",\"FullName\":\"Jon Doe\",\"UserName\":\"jdoe\"}"
```

Json Serializer returns empty []

```
var serializerSourceData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(deserializeSourceData)
```

serializerSourceData  looks like this

```
{"Id":[],"DisplayName":[],"Email":[],"FullName":[],"UserName":[]}
```

Any ideas how to get this desired format?

```
{ 
  DisplayName: "Jon Doe"
  Email: "JonDoe@gmail.com"
  FullName: "Jon Doe"
  Id: "178"
  UserName: "jdoe"
}
```

Comment: what is your json source? The double curly brackets is invalid json. Could you modify the source?

Comment: @MaartenDev the original source looks like this "{\"Id\":\"178\",\"DisplayName\":\"Jon Doe\",\"Email\":\"JonDoe@jpl.nasa.gov\",\"FullName\":\"Jon Doe\",\"UserName\":\"jdoe\"}" I added more context to my original post also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mixing in one bottle Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json serializers. JObject and JsonObject are completely different classes. You will have to select something one

Newtonsoft.Json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string sourceData="{\"Id\":\"178\",\"DisplayName\":\"Jon Doe\",\"Email\":\"JonDoe@jpl.nasa.gov\",\"FullName\":\"Jon Doe\",\"UserName\":\"jdoe\"}";
    
JObject deserializeSourceData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(sourceData);

//or this syntax is more clear and shorter
deserializeSourceData = JObject.Parse(sourceData);
     
sourceData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializeSourceData);

//or this syntax is more clear and shorter
sourceData = deserializeSourceData.ToString();
```

Now System.Text.Json

```
using System.Text.Json;

 JsonObject deserializeSourceData1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(sourceData);
     
sourceData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(deserializeSourceData1);
```

if you want to convert JObject to JsonObject, you can serialize a JObject to  a json string, and after this deserialize the json string to a JsonObject.

Comment: thanks the second option worked for me. I had to do everything using System.Text.Json. I think it has to do with me using .net core 6 now